# python cannot find module when using ssh

Tags: python, ssh

I'm using python on servers. When I run a python command which needs numpy module, if I do

```
ssh <server name> <python command>
```

> that server will complain no module named numpy found.

However, if I first ssh to that server by

```
ssh <server name>
```

then run that python command on that server

```
<python command>
```

everything will be ok.

This means that server has already been installed numpy module， and it just cannot find the module without my logging on it.

Any guess of what the problem could be?

Thanks

> Add:
>
> sorry for forgetting to mention that, the result I got by running

```
ssh <server name> which python
ssh <server name> echo $PYTHONPATH
ssh <server name> echo $PYTHONUSERBASE
ssh <server name> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

> are all the same as when I first ssh to the server

```
ssh <server name>
```

> then run those commands

```
which python
echo $PYTHONPATH 
echo $PYTHONUSERBASE
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It also means that your user's .bashrc has something specific in it which modifies `$PATH` to allow you to access extra modules. I don't like modifying path on a global level, personally, so I'll suggest the Python approach: call `sys.path.append('/path/to/numpy')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please have a look at the contents I added. Can it still be the problem of path. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It is truly the problem of python path.

And the reason why I didn't find this is that, instead of doing

```
ssh <server name> echo $PYTHONPATH
```

to find all the pathes python searches modules

we should do

```
ssh <server name> 'echo $PYTHONPATH'
```

we cannot ignore the quote to check variable PYTHONPATH on server

Answer (score 1):

When running cmd over ssh in one line, the .profile is not read.
To test, try this:

```
ssh host env
```

Use this instead to fix this issue (quotes are compulsory):

```
ssh host '. ~/.profile; cmd'
```

eg:

```
ssh <server name> '. ~/.bashrc; <python command>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and tried everything above.

What worked for me was changing the remote commands from python to the full path.

i.e.

1) SSH onto your remote, find out where your python is located via

2) change your command from `python pyscript.py` to `remote/path/to/python pyscript`

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure that you are using the same python environment.  You may be using one like /usr/bin/python when you log in, and perhaps using a different install such as /usr/local/bin/python when you are trying to run remotely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please have a look at the contents I added. I think the python environment when I log in and run remotely is the same.